# Reactjs function argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJs and have a question regarding the below code. Could someone explain me the removeTour code. why is id chosen as an argument in the function

```
const removeTour = (id) =>{
const newTours = tours.filter((tour) => tour.id !== id)
setTours(newTours)
}
```

One of the Components later again chosen in `onclick`. could you explain to me.

```
<button className="delete-btn" onClick={() =>{removeTour1(id)}}>Not Interested</button>
```

Comment: id is unique for each tour I guess. So it is used to find the tour and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be a unique identification number added to each `tour`, it can be used to identify a record/tour. So when a user clicks on the `Not Interested` button, you are calling the `removeTour1` function and passing it the id of the tour that needs to be removed.